# biblatex-chicago doesn't print bibliography using TeXworks

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago

I'm doing a large document on Overleaf but I need to upgrade to compile this document (1st figure) so I've tried to compile using TeXworks but It doesn't print the bibliography (2nd figure).

**what I need to do on TeXworks**

[image]

**What I got**

[image]

### My configuration

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
\fi
\usepackage[english]{babel} %
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{egameps}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\usepackage{makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{mathptmx}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}


% subsubsubsection
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}{\z@}{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{mathptmx}

\hypersetup{%
   colorlinks = {true},
   urlcolor = {black},
   linkcolor = {black},
   citecolor = {black},
}

\newenvironment{conditions*}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent
   \tabularx{\columnwidth}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}}
  {\endtabularx\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}

%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{table}{section}




%%%%%
%BIB
%%%%%

\usepackage[authordate, numbermonth=false,
            backend=biber, noibid, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldFormat{titleaddon}{%
   \mkbibbrackets{\ifcapital{\MakeCapital{#1\isdot}}{#1\isdot}}}

\begin{filecontents}{bib_test.bib}
@article{Owusu2016,
author = {Owusu, Phebe Asantewaa and Asumadu-Sarkodie, Samuel},
doi = {10.1080/23311916.2016.1167990},
issn = {23311916},
journal = {Cogent Engineering},
number = {1},
publisher = {Cogent},
title = {{A review of renewable energy sources, sustainability issues and climate change mitigation}},
volume = {3},
pages = {1--14},
year = {2016}
}
@article{Fell2017,
author = {Fell, Michael James},
doi = {10.1016/j.erss.2017.02.010},
issn = {22146296},
journal = {Energy Research and Social Science},
month = {may},
pages = {129--140},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {{Energy services: A conceptual review}},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{bib_test.bib}
%%%%%
%
%%%%%


\newcommand\fnote[1]{\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}\caption*{#1}}

\lhead{}
\cfoot{}                                    % left header: document author
\rfoot{\large\thepage}                      % center footer: page number
\clubpenalty=10000 \widowpenalty=10000 \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\def\qed{{\quad \vrule height 5pt width 5pt depth 0pt}}


\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}



\begin{document}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{labelname:poss}{#1's}
\newrobustcmd*{\posscitealias}{%
  \AtNextCite{%
    \DeclareNameWrapperAlias{labelname}{labelname:poss}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscite}{%
  \posscitealias
  \textcite}

\newrobustcmd*{\Posscite}{\bibsentence\posscite}

\newrobustcmd*{\posscites}{%
  \posscitealias
  \textcites}

\renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}

\autocite[11]{Owusu2016}. According to \textcite[137]{Fell2017} and  \cite{Fell2017}. Hence, energy services are a powerful engine of economic and social development.

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\begin{singlespace}
\printbibliography
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

*note: I had to change the biblatex.def*

```
%\newcommand*{\bibsetup}{%
%  \interlinepenalty=5000\relax
%  \widowpenalty=10000\relax
%  \clubpenalty=10000\relax
%  \raggedbottom
%  \frenchspacing
%  \biburlsetup}

%%% by

\appto{\bibsetup}{\sloppy}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What commands did you use for compilation? Did you use `biber`?

Comment: The backend is set to `biber`. It's working on my side if I run `pdflatex`, followed by `biber` followed by `pdflatex`. Make sure TexWorks compiles your project with this sequence.

Comment: It works!!!, why `biber`? why can't I use `pdfLaTex+...+` or `LuaLaTex+...+` or `XeLaTex+...+`?

Comment: @Celdor do you refere  `backend=biber` here `\usepackage[authordate, numbermonth=false, backend=biber, noibid, bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex-chicago}`?

Comment: @cdcarrion Yes, that's the one. Roughly speaking, `pdflatex` (and other engines) create PDFs with placeholders for citations on their first run. Then, `biber` manages the citations and substitutes placeholders with actual "citations". Then, one more run of the engine creates a correct PDF. This is the same with cross-references. If you see something like `??` in your document, run `pdflatex` one more time or even twice.